# communicating with mirc client using delphi

Tags: delphi

is there component which can allow me to communicate with mirc to connect to a specified server and then join to specified channel ?

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `idIRC` INDY component for Delphi

idIRC - client component, providing a fully functional IRC

OR

```
uses
   DdeMan;

 procedure mIRCDDE(Service, Topic, Cmd: string);
 var
   DDE: TDDEClientConv;
 begin
   try
     DDE := TDDEClientConv.Create(nil);
     DDE.SetLink(Service, Topic);
     DDE.OpenLink;
     DDE.PokeData(Topic, PChar(Cmd));
   finally
     DDE.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

example

```
mIRCDDE('mIRC', 'COMMAND', '/dde mirc connect "" stork.doc.ic.ac.uk,6667,#mIRC,1');
mIRCDDE('mIRC', 'COMMAND', '/say Hallo');
```

Comment: With the current versions of Delphi and mIRC, you need to use AnsiString.  The reason for this is that the default string type is WideString and this is incompatible with mIRC, which supports Ansi or Unicode (but responds in Ansi only).  I would edit the answer, but changing "String" to "AnsiString" is not enough of an edit to be accepted.